# GetLastWriteTime() is not displaying correct DateTime on my page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a aspx page in which I am displayng below code but I don't know where is the issue due to which it is not displaying modofied date correctly.

Expected Date to Display: 05/05/2016
Date Display Currently: 12/31/1600

Well, I didn't updated the file 400 years ago. Does anyone know what is the issue here?

```
<% 
   string pathfile = @"../../../Files/contact.csv";
   DateTime lastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(pathfile);
   string UpdatedDate = lastModified.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
%>
    <br /><b>(Contact last updated: <%Response.Write(UpdatedDate); %>)</b>
```

Comment: the directory path is bad / wrong. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583938/getlastwritetime-returning-12-31-1600-70000-pm)

Comment: @Jonesopolis which it seems to be bad directory path. It works on console application but not on my aspx page. And the link does not show anything related to directory path.

Comment: @Love0915 - The accepted answer in his link does mention a path.  It directly quotes the documentation on the subject.

Comment: Did worked but If I use the whole path example as `string path = @"c:\MyDir";` it works but when I publish this obviously path will be changed. So what is the solution for pathfile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetLastWriteTime` not always return reliable date time, use this

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan localOffset = now - now.ToUniversalTime();
DateTime lastModified = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(pathfile) + localOffset;
string UpdatedDate = lastModified.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

get iis server path this way, it will get `contact.csv` file from `Files` folder under the virtual directory where site deployed

```
string pathfile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Files/contact.csv");
```

server path info [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.aspx)

Comment: Did worked but If I use the whole path example as `string path = @"c:\MyDir";` it works but when I publish this obviously path will be changed. So what is the solution for pathfile ?

Comment: where is your file locate in project ?

Comment: Its a very long path file but that will be local path location. example `C:\web\src\dotnet\web\Files\contact.csv`

Comment: if you set the path directly then it won't change depend on site deployment in different location, it will take the file from the specified location from server

Comment: Worked as per `string pathfile = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Files/contact.csv");`

Comment: greate, happy coding

Comment: The accepted solution only corrects for local time. To get the correct time, be sure to pass the correct full path to getlastwritetime